# How to get Prometheus Node Exporter metrics with JSON format

Tags: go, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I deployed Prometheus Node Exporter pod on k8s. It worked fine.

But when I try to get system metrics by calling Node Exporter metric API in my custom Go application

```
curl -X GET "http://[my Host]:9100/metrics"
```

The result format was like this

```
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 1.7636e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 2.466e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 5.7992e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 9.1109e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0.004852894
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 1.291217651
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 11338
# HELP go_goroutines Number of goroutines that currently exist.
# TYPE go_goroutines gauge
go_goroutines 8
# HELP go_info Information about the Go environment.
# TYPE go_info gauge
go_info{version="go1.12.5"} 1
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes Number of bytes allocated and still in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_alloc_bytes 2.577128e+06
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total Total number of bytes allocated, even if freed.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total counter
go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total 2.0073577064e+10
.
.
.
something like this
```

Those long texts are hard to parse and I want to get the results in JSON format to parse them easily.

https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/issues/1062

I checked Prometheus Node Exporter GitHub Issues and someone recommended [prom2json](https://github.com/prometheus/prom2json).
But this is not I'm looking for. Because I have to run extra process to execute prom2json to get results. I want to get Node Exporter's system metric by simply calling HTTP request or some kind of Go native packages in my code.

How can I get those Node Exporter metrics in JSON format?

Comment: Why don't you use `prom2json` codebase as library? As far as I know, node exporter has no such endpoint that expose metrics in JSON format.

Comment: This is a standard Prometheus metrics format and all exporters will follow the same. I would rather ask, why do you want it in json format, that is, what is that you want to do with json format metrics?

Answer (score 1):

You already mentioned `prom2json` and you can pull the package into your Go file by importing `github.com/prometheus/prom2json`.

The [sample executable in the repo](https://github.com/prometheus/prom2json/blob/62ab84336b66a85df0fb29289f71f54454159337/cmd/prom2json/main.go) has the all building blocks you need. [First, open the URL](https://github.com/prometheus/prom2json/blob/62ab84336b66a85df0fb29289f71f54454159337/cmd/prom2json/main.go#L56-L58) and then [use the `prom2json` package to read the data](https://github.com/prometheus/prom2json/blob/62ab84336b66a85df0fb29289f71f54454159337/cmd/prom2json/main.go#L71-L73) and [store the result](https://github.com/prometheus/prom2json/blob/62ab84336b66a85df0fb29289f71f54454159337/cmd/prom2json/main.go#L88-L91).

However, you should also have a look at [expfmt.TextParser](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/common/expfmt#TextParser) as that is the native way to ingest Prometheus formatted metrics.

---

Comment: Thanks to @Oliver 's motivation(also thanks for Kamol too), I successfully got Prometheus Node Exporter metrics with JSON format by using prom2json as a code base.

I pulled prom2json package in my project and modified some codes for my own logic.

Here's my implementation without TLS configuration.
https://gist.github.com/jschoi126/dc80ebc6bb8d38b917728303975cc241

Since prom2json is using expfmt.TextParser inside the pacakge, Another answer can be using expfmt.TextParser.TextToMetricFamilies to parse original metric strings to JSON format.